# Uncaught TypeError. Undefined object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JS and I am getting this error:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is good practice but I mix plain javascript with jQuery. I heard it was bad practice but I also heard using plain JS is a lot faster. This is why i switch back and forth. I use jQuery to use their useful library

html:

```
<form class="contact-input" id="contact-form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
                <input id="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
                <input id="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
                <input id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-input-margin form-group">
                <input id="phonenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-input-margin col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea id="message" rows="8" class="form-control contact-margin" placeholder="Message...">
                </textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-xl">
</form>
```

js:

```
// Contact form submit
var contactFrom = document.getElementById("contact-form");
contactFrom.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted");
    create_post();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a jQuery method on `contactFrom`, which isn't a jQuery object.

Use `$(contactFrom)`:

```
var contactFrom = document.getElementById("contact-form");
$(contactFrom).on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted");
    create_post();
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wvtyn0m4/)

Comment: Does using `getElementById` then $(contactForm) have performance advantages compared to simple `$("#contact-form")`?

Comment: @Liondancer According to [this jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/44), `getElementById` will be faster even if it is wrapped with `$()`.